# Regex any number of _ between letters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that allows to have any number of _ between letters and was to have between 5 to 10 letters.

**Valid values:**

a_b_c_d_e

a_b_c_________________d_e

abcde

aa_bcd

**Non Valid values:**

_abcde

adebc_

a_________________________b

So far I came up with this but doesn't allow any number of _

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_]{3,8}[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: So you want to allow for 5-10 letters in total? What about "aa_bcd" and "abcde"?

Comment: @JvdV yes it's a valid value. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^[a-zA-Z](?:_*[a-zA-Z]){4,9}$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/uYlmnY/2)

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `[a-zA-Z]` | any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z' |
| `(?:` | group, but do not capture (between 4 and 9 times (matching the most amount possible)): |
| `_*` | '_' (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `[a-zA-Z]` | any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z' |
| `){4,9}` | end of grouping |
| `$` | before an optional \n, and the end of the string |

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question to include another valid test case. "abcde" and "abc_de" for instance are valid. Isn't required to have a _

Comment: @ezf06695  Use `^[a-zA-Z](?:_*[a-zA-Z]){4,9}$`